# Accessing two inputs for use in ${}

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes 3 inputs:

```
let logger = (title, date, type) => {
    switch(type) {
        case 'start' || 'end':
            console.log(`${title} loop ${type} time:  ${date.type}`);
            break;
    }
};


var startTime = new Date();
var endTime = new Date();
logger('tester', {start: startTime, end: endTime}, 'start');
```

I would like to do this without using a new variable.
As you can see I am trying to get the property from the object I pass in, I am trying to do this with `${}` but I am having trouble:

```
tester loop start: [object Object].start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **bracket notation** or **access properties directly**.

Usage with **bracket notation**:

```
let logger = (title, interval, type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'start' || 'end':
            console.log(`${title} loop ${type} time:  ${interval[type]}`);
            break;
    }
};
```

Usage with **dot notation**:

```
let logger = (title, interval, type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'start' || 'end':
            console.log(`${title} loop ${type} time:  ${interval.start}`);
            break;
    }
};
```

Example:

```
logger('tester', {start: new Date(), end: new Date()}, 'start');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use bracket notation:

```
console.log(`${title} loop ${type} time:  ${date[type]}`);
```